# Erro ao fazer restauração Banco de Dados Aplicação Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, wpf

Estou criando o backup do banco de dados, mas não consigo restaurar. Ele mostra o seguinte erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é meu código para realizar a restauração do banco a minha aplicação.

```
 try
        {
            var _with1 = openFileDialog1;
            _with1.Filter = ("DB Backup File|*.bak;");
            _with1.FilterIndex = 4;
            //Clear the file name
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                timer2.Enabled = true;
                SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
                cg.con.Open();
                string cb = "USE Master ALTER DATABASE [" + Application.StartupPath + "\\SISTEMA_CCA.bak] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate Restore database [" + Application.StartupPath + "\\SISTEMA_CCA.bak] FROM disk='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "' WITH REPLACE ALTER DATABASE [" + Application.StartupPath + "\\SISTEMA_CCA.bak] SET Multi_User ";
                cg.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
                cg.cmd.Connection = cg.con;
                cg.cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cg.con.Close();
                st1 = LB_Usuario.Text;
                st2 = "Restauração realizada com sucesso";
                cf.LogFunc(st1, System.DateTime.Now, st2);
                MessageBox.Show("Operação concluída com sucesso", "Restuaração do banco de dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

desde de já agradeço galera!

Comment: Passei por algo semelhante um tempo atrás e se não me engano era por causa do "\\" e era para SISTEMA_CCA.bak em todos os argumentos? assim como .StartupPath? A aplicação está na mesma máquina que o banco de dados?

Comment: Sim aplicação está na mesma maquina que o banco de dados, até eu finalizar o sistema, quando eu finalizar o sistema o banco será no servidor de banco e o sistema em outro servidor.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo você poderia me explicar como você resolveu o seu problema. Como disse que passou quase por essa mesma situação abraços!